# Expanding the QR Decomposition of square matrices to tall matrices

Tags: c

I'm trying to convert the QR Decomposition from "Numerical Recipes in C" to work with skinny (tall) matrices. Does anyone know how to do this? I believe the problem lies in how the householder is multiplied with the A but I am unable to figure it out.

```
void qrdcmp(float **a, int n, float *c, float *d, int *sing)
{
    int i,j,k;
    float scale,sigma,sum,tau;
        *sing=0;

    for (k = 1; k < n; k++) {
        scale = 0.0;
        for (i = k; i <= n; i++) scale = FMAX(scale, fabs(a[i][k]));
        if (scale == 0.0) { // Singular case.
            *sing = 1;
            c[k] = d[k] = 0.0;
        } else { // Form Qk and Qk · A.
            for (i = k; i <= n; i++) a[i][k] /= scale;
            for (sum = 0.0, i = k; i <= n; i++) sum += SQR(a[i][k]);
            sigma = SIGN(sqrt(sum), a[k][k]);
            a[k][k] += sigma;
            c[k] = sigma * a[k][k];
            d[k] = -scale * sigma;
            for (j = k + 1; j <= n; j++) {
                for (sum = 0.0, i = k; i <= n; i++) sum += a[i][k] * a[i][j];
                tau = sum / c[k];
                for (i = k; i <= n; i++) a[i][j] -= tau * a[i][k];
            }
        }
    }

    d[n] = a[n][n];
    if (d[n] == 0.0) *sing=1;
}
```

Comment: Am I right, that qrdcmp is for representing square matrix A as multiplication of orthogonal matrix Q and  upper triangular matrix R. Both Q and R are square by default, their multiplication A=QR is square as wall. qrdcmp has no sense for non-square matrix A*. rigth?

Comment: Do you want Q n×m and R square or the other way around? By the way you need a license to use the numerical recipes code, iirc.

Comment: I want it to build R as it does in the original code, by substituting values in A. Hence the R matrix must be m x n. About the license, I didn't find any license in my book? Or could you direct me to it and I will add it. Because the only comment in this function is on it's usage as.

Comment: Constructs the QR decomposition of a[1..n][1..n]. The upper triangular matrix R is returned in the upper triangle of a, except for the diagonal elements of R which are returned in d[1..n]. The orthogonal matrix Q is represented as a product of n− 1 Householder matrices
Q1 . . .Qn−1, where Qj = 1−uj ⊗uj/cj. The ith component of uj is zero for i = 1, . . . , j −1
while the nonzero components are returned in a[i][j] for i=j, .. , n. sing returns as true (1) if singularity is encountered during the decomposition, but the decomposition is still completed in this case; otherwise it returns false (0)